# Pattern identification in a dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset 'df' that looks something like this:

```
MEMBER  seen_1   seen_2   seen_3   seen_4   seen_5
  A       1        1        0         1       0
  B       1        1        1         0       1
  C       1        1        1         1       0
  D       0        0        0         1       0
```

As you can see there are several rows of ones and zeros.  Can anyone suggest me a code in python such that I am able to count the number of times '1' occurs continuously before the first occurrence of a 1 and 0 in order. For example for the fist member 'A' there are two ones occurring consequently before the first 1 and 0 appearance. Similarly for member 'B' there are three 1s that occur before a 1 and zero combination.  The resultant table should have a column something like this:

```
MEMBER  seen_1   seen_2   seen_3   seen_4   seen_5  event
  A       1        1        0         1       0       2   
  B       1        1        1         0       1       3 
  C       1        1        1         1       0       4
  D       0        0        0         1       0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not built for speed but it works.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

def counter(df):
    count = 0
    for value in df:
        if value!=0:
            count+=1
        elif count==0:
            pass
        else:
            break

    return count

df['event'] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(counter, axis=1)

df
Out[1]: 
  MEMBER  seen_1  seen_2  seen_3  seen_4  seen_5  event
0      A       1       1       0       1       0      2
1      B       1       1       1       0       1      3
2      C       1       1       1       1       0      4
3      D       0       0       0       1       0      1
```

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it. I have one small request. Can you please help me code a similar column in case I have a 1,0,and 0 simultaneous occurrence? The rest of the problem remains the same.

Comment: that can be done with panda methods, see my answer.
in general we should avoid using apply with loops

Comment: @ansev So what changes do I have to do here? Can you please help?where=(new_df.eq(0)&new_df.shift(axis=1).eq(1)).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) + [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
new_df=df.set_index('MEMBER')
where=(new_df.eq(0)&new_df.shift(axis=1).eq(1)).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0)
new_df['event']=new_df.where(where).sum(axis=1)
new_df=new_df.reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  MEMBER  seen_1  seen_2  seen_3  seen_4  seen_5  event
0      A       1       1       0       1       0    2.0
1      B       1       1       1       0       1    3.0
2      C       1       1       1       1       0    4.0
3      D       0       0       0       1       0    1.0
```

**Detail**

```
print(where)

        seen_1  seen_2  seen_3  seen_4  seen_5
MEMBER                                        
A         True    True   False   False   False
B         True    True    True   False   False
C         True    True    True    True   False
D         True    True    True    True   False
```